# VBA at Access - Filter with several criteria, where one criteria can be Null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got some problems with my vba code.
I got a form at access with a filter.

At the moment the one filter is for start/end date and a Person.
And because i am a noob, there is an other Filter for a cost centre and the start/end date.

I want to combine both, but with the case, cost centre can be Null or not. 
My "main" filter looks like this:

```
Private Sub Befehl51_Click()
If Nz(Me.txtvon, "") = "" Then             //StartDate
   MsgBox "Bitte Datumsbereich wählen!"
   Exit Sub
End If

If Nz(Me.txtbis, "") = "" Then            //EndDate
   MsgBox "Bitte Datumsbereich wählen!"
   Exit Sub
End If
 Me.Filter = "[TaetigkeitsDatum] between " & Format(Nz(Me!txtvon, Date),"\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & " 
and " & Format(Nz(Me!txtbis, Date), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & " And " & "[PersonalID] = " & Me.Liste0 & ""
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

The syntax for the cost criteria is like:

> [TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef] = "Kombinationsfeld145"

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You can just combine 2 filters with `And`? If you want to not filter on a field if it's `Null`, just use `([TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef] = "Kombinationsfeld145" Or [TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef]  Is Null)`

Comment: Well.. I want to combine both in one.. But the syntax is making me crazy. `Me.Filter = "[TaetigkeitsDatum] between " & Format(Nz(Me!txtvon, Date),"\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & " 
and " & Format(Nz(Me!txtbis, Date), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & " And " & "[PersonalID] = " & Me.Liste0 & "AND "& " [TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef] =" & Me!Kombinationsfeld145 & " OR  "[TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef] ( Is Null )""` is not working f.e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, there are just some minor SQL syntax errors.

I've written it to separate lines to increase readability and make understanding easier

```
Me.Filter = "[TaetigkeitsDatum] BETWEEN " & Format(Nz(Me!txtvon, Date),"\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & " AND " & Format(Nz(Me!txtbis, Date), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & _
            " AND [PersonalID] = " & Me.Liste0
If IsNumeric(Me!Kombinationsfeld145) Then
    Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND [TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef] =" & Me!Kombinationsfeld145
End If
```

Some of the changes I've made:

Spacing was off. Before every `And` and variable name, there should be a space.

The `" & "` between `And` and a variable name was unnecessary, removed that.

I've only included the comparison on `Me!Kombinationsfeld145` if it's numeric. That way, if it's `Null` or a zero-length string, it's not included in the comparison.

Comment: Hell yeah ur sick man ! Thanks ! Now its working with a number in "Kostenstelle", but if there is nothing inside it gives me a Runtime Error'3075' - Missing Operator.

Comment: Oh, I've misinterpreted what you wanted. If that field is null, do you want to ignore the check entirely, or do you want to match a null to a null?

Comment: I would ignore the check entirely if nothing is selected. BTW.: Thanks for ur fast and extensively replies! <3

Comment: See the current edit. It only appends the second condition if `Kombinationsfeld145` is numeric

Comment: `Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND ( [TaetigkeitsKostenstellenIDRef] =`  the one roundbracket is too much, but now it works perfectly !!